# how to find if the user interacting with bot is owner of the Team i.e. user's role is owner

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am working on creating bot for Microsoft teams in C#. User can interact with bot however there are some configurations that can be changed only by  a Owner of the team i.e. user with role as Owner.

I wrote the below code and it gives me user details but the role is null and for the Type, it says type is user.

```
var teamMember = await TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.From.Id, cancellationToken);
```

Is there a way to get the details if the user is owner of the team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll get what you need from GetMembersAsync, as you're finding out, but you can use MS Graph to get this info. Remember that a Teams team is also an MS 365 Group, so you can query the Group for Owners. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: When user install the app, OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync event gets fired and i save some user info in my azure database. I have to delete user data when app is uninstalled from the teams. The problem that i am facing is, i am not getting any event that is fired when someone uninstall the app.

Is there any way to achieve what i am looking for?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to detect this right now - I'm hoping it's something we get from Teams in the future